# Assembly: data segment when called from C or created as an independent program

Tags: c, assembly, data-segment

I'm confused about this; I don't think that there should be any difference 
in both cases , the program ends up as exe file. 
Please  help if you think a differ....

Let me clarify my question:
Is there is a difference  in the data segment  definition   or handling
between when I create an assembly program  'stand alone' and  when I call for an assembly routine   from  a **C** program?

Who is defining the location  or size  of the date segment in both cases?
Is this  the compiler, or the operating system?
And how  the  value of the data segment determined in both cases?

Comment: You need to make this question much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**Depend of operating system!**

If we are looking for windows operating system under IA32 then API reserve virtual memory address space of some application and:

- CS segment, point to the start of
  program or code memory.
- DS segment, point to the start of
  variable or data memory.
- SS segment, point to the start of
  stack memory and is the same as DS.
- ES as extra segment normally is in
  use for string transfer instructions
  (lodsb, stosw, ...) and is the same as DS.
- FS as another extra segment point
  on OS kernel data like [Win32 Thread Information
  Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block).
- GS as another extra segment is
  0 as beginning of allocated virtual memory address space of loaded application.

Exsample of accessing 'Win32 Thread Information Block' via FS segment:

```
function GetThreadId: integer;
//result := GetCurrentThreadId;
asm
  mov   eax, fs:[$18]      //eax := thread information block
  mov   eax, [eax + $24]   //eax := thread id
end; { GetThreadId }
```

Sheck also: [x86 memory segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_register)